# is there a way to break list into columns using VueJs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a List which is being rendered using v-for and i am outputting the data into one column. Is there a way that after a certain width and height, the data flows into next column without making any new Array? Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/bGGOQBz).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [{
          text: 'Item1'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item2'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item3'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item4'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item5'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item6'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item7'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item8'
        },
        {
          text: 'Item9'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout class="mt-3 ml-4">
      <v-flex md-4>
        <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list.text">
          {{list.text}}
        </div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex md4>
        //After a certain width and height, make data flow into this column?
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I prefer to use widths and heights instead of creating a new Array just so that i don't have to lot of manual adjustments throughout the code to deal with the new array.

Comment: If your list has a fixed height there are a number of solutions for this. Flex columns and wrapping for instance.

Comment: I actually don't have a fixed height set up on it so i would actually go with the easiest viable option possible i guess.

Comment: The easiest solution has nothing to do with Vue. Simply use CSS to modify the layout. You don't need to create a new array unless you wanted to split the columns at an exact spot (eg after the last item that starts with A).

Comment: @BryceHowitson That makes sense. I thought i had to do it with Vue lol. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Do you need help with the CSS? I'd remove the second `v-flex` and convert the first one into a wrapper with a class in an effort to make your markup easier to style.

Comment: @BryceHowitson If you can show an example, that would help out a ton. thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CSS to easily create columns. Just use a `v-for` to get the content on the screen then style it with CSS. In your case the loop will append multiple `<div>` elements. Here's an example of CSS columns.

This is the most basic solution where `column-count: 3` splits the list into 3 equal columns.

```css
.column_wrapper {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_wrapper">
  <!-- results of <div v-for="item in list"></div>  -->
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
  <div>Item 10</div>
  <div>Item 11</div>
  <div>Item 12</div>
  <div>Item 13</div>
  <div>Item 14</div>
  <div>Item 15</div>
</div>
```

The downfall of this solution is that the browser will ALWAYS try to break the list into 3 columns. If you only want the columns to split after a specific height, you can use `flex-box`

For example (if the list is longer than what fits into 200px tall)

```css
.column_wrapper {
    max-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_wrapper">
  <!-- results of <div v-for="item in list"></div>  -->
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
  <div>Item 10</div>
  <div>Item 11</div>
  <div>Item 12</div>
  <div>Item 13</div>
  <div>Item 14</div>
  <div>Item 15</div>
</div>
```

*Note:* in both examples **the location at which it splits is arbitrary** (as in the brower decides when to move to the next column). If you need to decide where it breaks, creating a new array for each column in vue is your best bet.