# How to put components on two columns using VueJS Vuetify Grid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, grid, vuetify.js

I want to align two components to show some data on two columns, I've followed the official tutorial  [Vuetify Grid](https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid). On my case components are fixed like a rows list, on the screen I put the red square to show my goal, and show the result of the code. Also, I tried changing `row` to `column` but not works, it keep on two rows.

```
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs6>Associado: {{item.nameUser}}</v-flex>
        <v-flex xs6>Associado: {{item.nameUser}}</v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

[image: sample image]

complete code

```
    <template>
  <v-content class="pa-1" fluid>
    <v-btn
      color="blue"
      dark
      small
      fixed
      bottom
      right
      fab
      @click="showRegisterTransactionDialog = true"
    >
      <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-data-table
      :mobile-breakpoint="NaN"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="transactionsLocal"
      :items-per-page="3000"
      :hide-default-footer="true"
      :single-expand="singleExpand"
      :expanded.sync="expanded"
      item-key="id"
      show-expand
      sort-by="showDate"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
          <v-toolbar-title>Fluxo de caixa</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:item.value="{ item }">
        <div style="color:green;" v-if="item.type == 'entry'">{{item.value}}</div>
        <div v-else style="color:red;">{{item.value}}</div>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
        <v-container>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs6>Associado: {{item.nameUser}}</v-flex>
            <v-flex xs6>Associado: {{item.nameUser}}</v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>

    <RegisterTransactionDialog
      @hideRegisterTransactionDialog="showRegisterTransactionDialog = false"
      :show="showRegisterTransactionDialog"
    ></RegisterTransactionDialog>
  </v-content>
</template>
```

**UPDATE**

I've set background color to black on `v-container` and discover that the problem is it. But, I don't know fix it too.

`<v-container style="background-color: black;">`

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce. There's something else messing up your layout.

Comment: i couldn't see any problem when i test your case here: https://codepen.io/salihtopcu/pen/yLYQYob
are you sure that there's no style definitions that may cause this issue?

Comment: No, there's not. I just posted the whole code, It's used inside a `v-data-table`, maybe have something to do it.

Comment: [Here is a solution that you can consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919057/is-there-a-way-to-break-list-into-columns-using-vuejs)

Answer (score 6):

Why not try using something like this instead of v-flex:

```
<v-col cols="12" md="6">
</v-col>

<v-col cols="12" md="6">
</v-col>
```